# Modal verb omission?

Tags: grammar, interpretation

> Because methodology is fully exposed, genuine defects may be revealed, or more frustratingly, discussion sidetracked away from implications.

I wonder if the modal verb "may be" which is following "genuine defects" is omitted between discussion and sidetracked for the writer's convenience.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> defects may be revealed, or ... discussion sidetracked

This is a standard case of omitting repeated words in a parallel structure; it has the same meaning as:

> defects **may be** revealed, or ... discussion **may be** sidetracked

Also, as a terminology correction to your question, only “may” is a modal verb here; “be” is an auxiliary verb used to form the passive voice of the main verbs “reveal” and “sidetrack”.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just remove "may be",  "genuine defects revealed".  It is possible to say "genuine defects are revealed"  but the meaning changes.

The orginal sentence has a subordinate "because" clause with one reason.  The main clause starts at "genuine..."

If you remove "may be",  then the only way to parse the meaning would be to interpret it as

> Because {methodology is fully exposed, [and] genuine defects revealed}, ...

So "genuine defects [are] revealed would become one of the reasons in the subordinate "because" clause.  This changes the meaning.  The whole expression becomes the "because" clause, and there is no main clause.  It is hard to parse, and confusing. It took me several readings to decide that it didn't make sense and was ungrammatical.

If you change to "are revealed" the sentence is grammatically correct, but you use the "it is possible" meaning of "may".

So you can't omit or modify the word "may" without changing the meaning.